# How to trigger Microsoft Flow using SPFx Extension's ListView Command set

Tags: spfx, microsoft-flow, listviewcommandset

As the title says, How to trigger Microsoft Flow using SPFx Extension's ListView Command set?

Has anyone tried this and get it to work?

Please guide me to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you can get help from below link:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/download-sharepoint-list-item-pdf-using-microsoft-flow-maniyani